# Copy Dir from local server to the remote server using SCP in GOLANG

Tags: go

I am using

github.com/tmc/scp

package for copying files from the local server to remote server, I found the implementation easy, but when i use this for copying the directory it doesn't work properly.
It takes the directory path also as a file and just creates a file with directory name in the remote server.

My current code implementation is below

```
//PerformSCP Input keypath, remote ip,ssh port , source dir, destn dir, remote user
func PerformSCP(keyPath, remoteIP, sshPort, srcDir, destDir, remoteUser string) error {
    Debug("Inside PerformSCP")
    key, err := getKeyFile(keyPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Define the Client Config
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "root",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.PublicKeys(key),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: func(hostname string, remote net.Addr, key ssh.PublicKey) error {
            return nil
        },
    }
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", remoteIP+":"+sshPort, config)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    srcFileList, _ := SearchDir(srcDir)//gives list of all file and folder paths within the folder path passed
    for _, k := range srcFileList {
        session, err := client.NewSession() // because of 'StdinPipe after process started' error need to close and then again create session for all copy
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        err = scp.CopyPath(k, destDir, session)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            return err
        }
        session.Close()
    }

    return nil
}
```

Is there any other package which can help me with folder copy using scp

I post this question so it helps me as well others having same requirement in the future as well

TIA

Comment: I think this package worth to try https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/sftp. Never use it, but after fast reading the doc, it more roubust than the package that you use above. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes its better only thing is that i have the limit of using scp

Comment: scp is the same as sftp internally. You can use it.